# PHP MSSQL there are no more rows in active result

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this code in php where it runs if I try to run each while loop separately, but when I tried to do a nested whileloop it ouputed an error of

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set. Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved. in C:\xampp\htdocs\survey-module\survey.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\survey-module\survey.php(13): PDOStatement->fetch() #1 {main} thrown in
```

Here is Php Code

```
   $survey_detail=$survey->viewSurvey('3');
        $questions=$survey->indexQuestion('3');

        while ($question_header = $header_questions->fetch()){
            while ($question_detail = $questions->fetch()){
                if($question_detail['header']==$question_header['header']){
                echo $question_detail['header'] . "-".$question_detail['question']. "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: May [this](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201017/sql-server-pdo-error-there-are-no-more-rows-in-the-active-result-set-since-thi) one is help.

Comment: @JaydeepMor cant understand their laguange tho

Comment: He said "One way to resolve this is to inform the server that the query / command has ended and that no type of synchronization is required. Call the closeCursor() method after the execute()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apprently MSSQL doesnt allow multiple fetching in a nested while, so what I did is fetch the data and put it in a associative array, here is the code.

```
$question_array = array();
while ($question = $questions->fetch()) {
    $question_push = array('header'=>$question['header'],'question'=>$question['question']);
    array_push($question_array,$question_push);
}
while ($question_validation =$header_questions->fetch()) {
    foreach ($question_array as $key => $value) {
        if($question_validation['header']==$value['header'])
        {
            echo $value['header'] ."-". $value['question'] ."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fetch data and compare it to null, because what I found is that when you fetch last row, the next one becomes null and then fetching the next one will throw an exception `There are no more rows in the active result set`.

This is strange and should not work - I would prefer to get `false` value when trying to fetch non existing row.

Nevertheless - it works and I won't complain ;)

```
 $survey_detail=$survey->viewSurvey('3');
        $questions=$survey->indexQuestion('3');

        while (($question_header = $header_questions->fetch()) !== null){
            while (($question_detail = $questions->fetch()) !== null){
                if($question_detail['header']==$question_header['header']){
                echo $question_detail['header'] . "-".$question_detail['question']. "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```